# Library to determine indefinite article of a noun?

Tags: c#

Are there any libraries for .NET that deal with determining the [Indefinite Article](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/540/01/) of a noun?

My crude attempt is below, which will probably work for 99% of my usage (which is acceptable) just wondering if there are any established alternatives?

```
public static string GetIndefinateArticle(string noun)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(noun))
        return noun;

    var first = noun[0];

    if(first == 'a' ||
        first == 'e' ||
        first == 'i' ||
        first == 'o')
        return "an " + noun;

    return "a " + noun;
}
```

**Update**: Eamon pointed out a duplicate question in the comments: [How can I correctly prefix a word with "a" and "an"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288291/how-can-i-correctly-prefix-a-word-with-a-and-an) I'll leave this Q here and open though, because I still don't really have an answer.

Comment: According to Grammar Girl, The use of Indefinite Article is based on the sound of the noun, Worth note it here, i think. http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/

Comment: yeah i realise this, but determining the sound from ascii is rather difficult! Hence wondering if there are any libs which presumably check for common starting letter combinations grouped based on their sound?

Comment: you should switch the "a " and "an ".

Comment: `self`? is that a synonym for `this`? or what is that? should it have been `noun`?

Comment: in some programming languages it's called "self", in some "this". It's the same thing.

Comment: no, its my crappy proof reading, fixed

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288291/how-can-i-correctly-prefix-a-word-with-a-and-an

Comment: I've implemented an actual lirary since this question was asked; see http://eamon.nerbonne.org/2013/04/a-vs-determine-appropriate-english.html or use nuget and install AvsAn.

Answer (score 7):

If this is something you need done seriously, you may consider porting the Ruby Linguistics (English) library to .Net.  It's open source & does a pretty good job of calculating the correct articles.

http://deveiate.org/projects/Linguistics/

Comment: +1 for answering the question (is there a library) rather than cobbling together some code.

Comment: Seeing as IronRuby has just been released, there may be no need to port! I shall play tomorrow. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Since all you're really doing is check for patterns in the string, you could use a regular expression.  This should also allow for future expansion of letter combos like *lutge098* talked about:

```
public static string GetIndefinateArticle(string noun)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(noun, "^([aeio]|un|ul)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        return "an " + noun;
    else
        return "a " + noun;
}
```

Comment: It will be a long and difficult regex probably, but more effective

Comment: @lugte You haven't seen a long and difficult regex until you've seen the proper way of validating an email address. It was **over 6 lines long!**

Comment: @Earlz If you put it that way, i guess i haven't :D

Answer (score 4):

I implemented a library to do this: https://github.com/eamonnerbonne/a-vs-an; it's AvsAn on nuget.  It's based on real usage patterns in wikipedia and hence even deals well with tricky things like...

- "an 0800 number"
- "an ∞ of oregano"
- "a NASA flight"
- "an NSA analyst"

In other words, it usually even will deal reasonably with many things that aren't normal words.

Answer (score 3):

I've ported a function from [Python](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ibid-core/ibid/trunk/annotate/987/ibid/utils/__init__.py#L301) that correctly determines vowel sounds in C# and posted it as an answer to the question [Programmatically determine whether to describe an object with a or an?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558437/programmatically-determine-whether-to-describe-an-object-with-a-or-an/8044744#8044744).  You can see the code snippet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558437/programmatically-determine-whether-to-describe-an-object-with-a-or-an/8044744#8044744).  It is indeed more complicated than just looking at vowels.

Answer (score 0):

What i would do is:

```
var first = noun[0];
var second = noun[1];

if(first == 'a' ||
    first == 'e' ||
    first == 'i' ||
    first == 'o')
    return "an " + self;

if(first == 'u')
    if (second == 'n' ||
        second == 'l')
        return "an " + self;

if(first == 'h')
    if (second == 'i')
        return "an " + self;

return "a " + self;
```

So you can define some cases where some letters in combination with each other form a certain sound. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your `if` statement for `h` is very wrong. It would produce `an hit` and `a honor`, both of which are incorrect.

Comment: Are you familiar with a control statement called `switch`?

Comment: @Matthew Ferreira: keep in mind that this is just an example of concept.

Comment: The h is an unsolvable problem without a dictionary.  Make your program speak Cockney, they always have a silent h so you can always pick "an".

Comment: I think that the question itself is unsolvable. Many words also have multiple pronunciations which are valid.

Comment: @Matthew Ferreira yeah i appreciate its probably very difficult to solve completely for this reason, however i'll willingly accept a solution that works most of the time, was just looking for the best way to achieve "most"

Comment: The 'u' solution is also incorrect - you will end up with *an uniform* and *a umbrella*. Like i mentioned in my answer there are a lot of complexities to look for, which can make your code a bit of a beast.

Answer (score 0):

The basic rule of "a" before a consonant and "an" before a vowel gets you most of the way there, that would be very easy to implement. The problem is the "sounds-like a vowel = an" case -- that would be much harder.

Answer (score 0):

No, and it isn't as simple as just whacking an extra `n` when the next character is a vowel. There are a whole bunch of subtleties around it, and you also have to consider how to handle `h` - some use `an` before it, some don't.

This is also English specific, and the framework is relatively language agnostic.

This means you will have to cook it up yourself :)