# Simple way in JS to prepend a string with an indefinite article?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a list of product names that will need to be prepended with an [indefinite article](http://www.englishpage.com/articles/a-vs-an.htm). My products look something like this:

1. Book
2. App
3. eBook
4. Record

These are stored in a DB and passed into a React app. I need to programmatically prepend each product with “a” or “an” accordingly, so they would appear like:

1. A Book
2. An App
3. An eBook
4. A Record

Is there a simple way to pull this off with JS alone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript library to determine indefinite article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366516/javascript-library-to-determine-indefinite-article)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var nouns = [ "Book", "App", "eBook", "Record" ];
var vocals = "aeiouAEIOU";

for ( var n = 0; n < nouns.length; n++ )
{
     var first = nouns[n][0];
     if ( vocals.indexOf(first) >= 0 )
         nouns[n] = "An " + nouns[n];
     else
         nouns[n] = "A " + nouns[n];
}
console.log(nouns);
```

gives

```
 ["A Book", "An App", "An eBook", "A Record"]
```

on the console. Thanks to the simplicity of the English grammar. That won't work in any other language!

Comment: Sadly this breaks down in some cases, such as "user" (this snippet gives you "an user"). Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15366802/2664985) for a more complete (and more complex) solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple code that checks the first letter of the given word and use the correct article:

```js
function prependArticle(word){
  var vowels = 'aeiou';
  var firstLetter = word[0].toLowerCase();
  if(vowels.indexOf(firstLetter) > -1)
    return 'An ' + word;
  else
    return 'A ' + word;
}

//Test the function:
document.write(prependArticle('Book') + '<br/>');
document.write(prependArticle('App') + '<br/>');
document.write(prependArticle('eBook') + '<br/>');
document.write(prependArticle('Record') + '<br/>');
```

However, that's not perfect. For instance the word "Unicorn" starts with "U", yet it should prepended with "A", not "An". Similarly, the word "Hour" start with "H" yet, it should be prepended with "An", not "A". Also acronyms have some complexity because we prepend them based on how we pronounce them, not how we write them.

Comment: Thanks so much! I accepted the other answer since they're both so similar and his came first. I upvoted yours, too. I was thinking the same thing… hard to make this bulletproof. Fortunately it's for a limited set of products, so I can build in some sort of acception list that trumps the conditional.